# Sharing state between sibling components with routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, restful-architecture

I am building a small application with the intention of learning some design principles (api/data structure) along with new frameworks and languages, specifically ReactJS w/ Redux on the Frontend and Golang on the backend (restful API).

I am struggling with how I should structure components and routes, along with my API, based on the react container component [way of thinking](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) in which single responsibility principle is followed. As

Let's say I have two objects types, `Companies` and `Houses` which all reside in a `City` and may have some commonalities such as a `Street`. With that said, I will want my web application to be aware of these commonalities. I believe I would structure the API as follows:

GET/PUT/POST/DELETE:

`https://0.0.0.0/api/companies`

```
  [
   { "id": 102650,
    "name": "Corp",
    "street": "Savannah",
    "content": "..."
    }, ...
  ]
```

`https://0.0.0.0/api/houses`

```
[
  { "id": 40,
    "name": "Old Brick House",
    "street": "Savannah",
    "content": "..."
  },...
]
```

`https://0.0.0.0/api/city`

```
{
  companies: [{
    "id": 102650,
    "name": "Old Brick House",
    "street": "Savannah",
    "content": ".."
  },...]
 houses: [
  {
    "id": 40,
    "name": "Old Brick House",
    "street": "Savannah",
    "content": ".."
  },...]
}
```

Now for my React container component structure I would have (I know the below snippet is wrong... this is where I need help):

```
...
<BrowserRouter>
  <City>
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/Houses" component={ Houses } /> <!-- Where to pass data? -->
      <Route path="/Components" component={ Components } />
   </Switch>
  </City>
 </BrowserRouter>
...
```

Where `City` would be the one to make the `GET` call to endpoint `https://0.0.0.0/api/city` so that the sibling containers could have access to each other's data (assume both containers are simple lists with CRUD commands).

Now for my questions: How should I pass data to the seperate routed components (`Houses` and `Companies`)? Also, am I designing the api correctly? As of now, I will never call `GET` on my `houses` or `companies` endpoints b/c I'll always be fetching at the city level due to the ReactJS structure.

Comment: Hey @s1r-lanzelot, did you ever find an answer to your question? I'm going through the same thing (sharing data between sibling top-level components)

Comment: @robinmetral sorry, I stopped using react awhile back. I can't remember how I handled this and no longer have access to the source code.

Comment: No worries. Thank you and take care!